# Setting ListView scroll position nicely in Android

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I am aware of `setSelection()`, `setSelectionFromTop()`, and `setSelectionAfterHeaderView()`, but none of them seems to do what I want.

Given an item in the list, I want to scroll so that it is in view.  If the item is above the visible window of the list, I want to scroll until the item is the first visible item in the list; if the item is below the visible window, I want it to scroll up until it is the last visible item in the list.  If the item is already visible, I don't want any scrolling to occur.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Why don't those methods you mentioned work? What happens when you setSelection on the item you want? (I'm aware it's an old question. If you've solved this by now, please post your solution, I would appreciate it)

Comment: @T3Roar: I did solve it, with a combination of setSelection() and setSelectionFromTop(), worrying about the list height and the item height, and of course the item's position within the list.  It's a mess, I'm afraid, and I can't share the code anyway - but it's solvable.  Maybe if I get the chance I'll write up a generic solution that I can share, but what I've got right now just isn't useful outside of the context I've got it in.  Sorry!

Comment: Well I'm glad it only took some use of setSelection() to achieve rather than some other crazy workaround. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: Hey Carl, have you done any work on a more generic solution for this issue? I am working on a listview and I need a similar behavior to set selection to an item. I'd appreciate it if you could share any more knowledge or work you've done on this matter. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I have not, @Gix, but thanks for the reminder.  I should do this; I'm sorry I still haven't gotten to it.

Answer (score 15):

It occurs because listView isn't created yet.  Try to post runnable such as:

```
getListView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        lst.setSelection(15);
    }
},100L);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think, I was looking for the same, then I found the following solution:

```
if (listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() > pos 
    || listview.getLastVisiblePosition() <= pos) {
    listview.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
}
```

**API 8** is required to use `smoothScrollToPosition` (which is a reasonable minimum anyways) so you are aware.

Answer (score 3):

Sergey's answer works, but I believe that the right way of doing this is setting up an observer to be notified when the `ListView` has been created.

```
listView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
     new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
 @Override
 public void onGlobalLayout() {
     scrollTo(scrollToPosition);
     listView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
 }
});
```

Comment: this is a better solution but don't forget to remove the listener:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)

Comment: Thank you Rocel. The line listView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this) does that

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to [Sergey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6873176/1647855) is to call `setSelection()` later in the Activity/Fragment life cycle, perhaps in `onStart()`. That way, you have a guarantee that the View is ready rather than using some arbitrary delay.