# How to adjust layout that contains LeftBar and RightBar when soft keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: layout picture]

My application has right and left bars that have some controls and those bars **should be fixed**. Body has edit text fields for input info by user. When soft keyboard appears (that is custom) then appropriate edit text **should be visible** above the keyboard.

I know that there is such option in Manifest as `android:windowSoftInputMode` but I can not find my issue. I can get my layout move up above keyboard (with bars) that is unacceptable, or staying layout without any move so I get edit text editing that are hidden by my keyboard.

Please help me with this issue?

My layout sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100.0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="200.0dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dip">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/createuser_textView_logo"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="@string/createuser_text_logo"
                    style="@style/TextActivityLogo"/>


            <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/createuser_textView_logo"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/createuser_textView_text"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:text="@string/createuser_text_text"
                            style="@style/TextActivityText"/>

                    <com.mycompany.myapp.views.MyEditText
                            android:id="@+id/createuser_editText_username"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/createuser_textView_text"
                            android:hint="@string/createuser_edit_username"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/createuser_editText_password"
                            style="@style/MyEditText"/>

                    <com.mycompany.myapp.views.MyEditText
                            android:id="@+id/createuser_editText_password"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/createuser_editText_username"
                            android:hint="@string/createuser_edit_password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/createuser_editText_username"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/createuser_editText_firstname"
                            style="@style/MyEditText"/>

                    <com.mycompany.myapp.views.MyEditText
                            android:id="@+id/createuser_editText_firstname"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/createuser_editText_password"
                            android:hint="@string/createuser_edit_firstname"
                            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/createuser_editText_password"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/createuser_editText_lastname"
                            style="@style/MyEditText"/>

                    <com.mycompany.myapp.views.MyEditText
                            android:id="@+id/createuser_editText_lastname"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/createuser_editText_firstname"
                            android:hint="@string/createuser_edit_lastname"
                            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/createuser_editText_firstname"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/createuser_editText_email"
                            style="@style/MyEditText"/>


                    <com.mycompany.myapp.views.MyEditText
                            android:id="@+id/createuser_editText_email"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/createuser_editText_lastname"
                            android:hint="@string/createuser_edit_email"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
                            android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
                            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/createuser_editText_lastname"
                            style="@style/MyEditText"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.mycompany.myapp.views.LeftNavigationBar
            android:id="@+id/left_nav_bar"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.mycompany.myapp.views.RightNavigationBar
            android:id="@+id/right_nav_bar"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want the keyboard to alter some layouts on your screen while other layouts should stay intact. I am not sure if this is possible with normal behavior.

However if you can somehow [grab the event when the soft keyboard shows up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793093/android-edittext-soft-keyboard-show-hide-event) then you could change the [listview scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313483/setting-listview-scroll-position-nicely-in-android) to show the desired textviews. If your keyboard is blocking the layout even when scrolled to top you can just add margin to the listview.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I thought that this is the only way to solve the problem and I did it so. It works:)